# Jmeter-Recording issue

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record a http web page using JMeter 2.3.3 version. I have setup the JMeter proxy and tried, but didn't work. I have followed the below steps.

1. Launch jmeter 2.3.3, added thread group to test plan
2. Under Workbench->add->non-test elements-> added HTTP proxy server. proxy server setting are port:9090, target:use recording controller, grouping:donot group samplers, Type:HTTp request and checked the boxes of all under http sampler settings
3. Saved the settings
4. Now in browser(IE 7.0 or firefox 3.0.16), under connection settings, setup the manual proxy settings as local host and port as 9090 (no auto detect settings nothing, only manual proxy). Setting saved
5. Now in the JMeter, started the http proxy server.
6. Open a browser and hit the webpage needs to be tested.

The page is not opened. In fact because of the changes made in browsers, no pages are opened. Whenever I try hitting a page, the pages are recorded in the JMeter. But without the page open, how can I test.

I looking for an immediate answer and my work is blocked. Immediate answer would be appreciated.

Comment: One of the best ways to get answers is to have a question that is easy to read. This isn't.  Please edit it, put in a few linebreaks.

Comment: I improved the formatting a bit.

Comment: @jonny - did you ever figure out the problem? It's always a good idea to help out future people who come across this same problem, by adding your solution as an answer to your question.

Comment: @TarynEast - I think you can forget it, he got his urgent fix :)

Comment: Yeah - but sometimes it's worth adding a comment in case he ever comes back :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you need to configure JMeter to [use a proxy](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) in order to load the pages you're trying to test.

Answer (score 1):

Please Configure your browser with Address:localhost and port:8080. and then start recording the script.

Steps:

1. Open browser IE.
2. Go to option and select connection.
3. Select "LAN Setting".
4. set Address:"localhost" and port:8080.

Follow this step and start recording script.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have checked the redirect automatically check box in the HTTP Proxy settings in JMeter.